# matching digits and repetition in autocmd BufNewFile

Tags: autocmd

I've got a template for vimwiki diary entries that's invoked via this autocommand:

```
autocmd BufNewFile ~/Documents/wiki/diary/*.mkd :silent 0r !vimwiki-diary-template.py
```

But I want to be able to create other `*mkd` files in that directory without that template being invoked.

The times I want the diary template to be invoked are when new file name is like `2020-09-21.mkd`.  So I'd like to be able to change the autocmd to something like...

```
autocmd BufNewFile ~/Documents/wiki/diary/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.mkd :silent 0r !vimwiki-diary-template.py
```

But that doesn't work.

And I don't see anything in `:help autocmd-patterns` about integers/digits/numerals/numbers.

If I do `ls ~/Documents/wiki/diary | grep -E '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.mkd'` that shows the files I want this template to be applied to.  But I don't know how to utilize that regex in the vim autocmd.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patterns used in auto-commands are different from normal regexes. In [`:help file-pattern`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#file-pattern) you'll see that you actually need `\\\{m,n\}` to specify repetition of an item.

So, in your case, what you actually want is:

```
autocmd BufNewFile ~/Documents/wiki/diary/[0-9]\\\{4\}-[0-9]\\\{2\}-[0-9]\\\{2\}.mkd :silent 0r !vimwiki-diary-template.py
```

Note that in some of those cases, it might be easier to just repeat the `[0-9]` a few times, rather than to deal with this somewhat awkward syntax.

Comment: I saw that line in the `:help` but didn't know what it meant.  When I saw the `m,n` part it made me think of a **range** rather than **quantity**.

Comment: @alec autocommand patterns have more in common with shell globs than regex